# Keep Flash element active in Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and embedded a Flash IRC client on the popup page. The problem is, that it doesn't stay active, when the popup is hidden and restarts when the popup opens. Is there a way to keep that element active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with using a Flash object, but with the way popups work in Chrome Extensions. The page in a popup (typically `popup.html`) doesn't exist at all when the popup is closed, so your Flash object doesn't "live" anywhere. So basically, the popup isn't just "hidden", it's closed and stops running.

Sadly [the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) is not explicit about that.

As far as I know, only the background page continues running at all times. If you were able to communicate through JavaScript with the Flash object, you might be able to have the background page run the Flash and store the messages, and whenever the popup is open, the popup page and the background page could use message passing so that the popup can display the messages that happened while it was closed. But that doesn't sound great.

Another alternative would be to open a popup window like we used to in the old days. :)